# Spectrum of a linear function in the continous functions

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory, banach-algebras

I am currently working through my course text and one of the examples for a unital, commutative Banach algebra is the space of continuous functions $C([a,b])$. Further, in the text, there is a theorem stating:

> $\sigma(a) \neq 0$  $\forall a \in \mathcal{A}$, for $\mathcal{A}$ being a unital algebra.

This theorem is also closely related to the Gelfand Mazur Theorem.

Trying a few examples I came across the linear function $f(x) = x$, which is obviously in $C([0,1])$, and for which $\lambda id - f$ seems to be invertable for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$. Thus f must have the resolvent $\rho(f) = \mathbb{C}$ and therefore $\sigma(f) = \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{C} = \emptyset$ contradicting the theorem stated before. Does anyone see my mistake?

Comment: $\lambda id-f$ is invertible for all $\lambda$ except one...

Comment: I still don't get it, could you enlighten me? I have tried various numbers. My only guess would be for $\lambda = f(x)$ but it has to be valid for all $x \in [0,1]$, no?

Comment: $f=id$, then if you take $\lambda=1$ you get the $0$ map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for my misunderstanding was supposing that we look for the inverse regarding the composition of functions when it was rather the multiplicative inverse we were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the identity of the Banach algebra $C([0,1])$, which you denote by $\mathrm{id}$, is the constant function $\mathbf 1 \colon x \mapsto 1$. So, for $a \in C([0,1])$, $\lambda \in \mathbf C$, we have (as elements of $C([0,1])$ have inverses iff the do not have zeros:
\begin{align*}
   \lambda \in \sigma(a) &\iff \lambda \mathbf 1 - a \text{ is not invertible}\\
      &\iff \exists x \in [0,1]: \lambda - a(x) = 0 \\
      &\iff \lambda \in a([0,1]) 
\end{align*}
So, the spectrum of an element of $C([0,1])$ equals its range as a function, so for $f \colon x \to x$ we have $\sigma(f) = [0,1]$.